# ember data createRecord without relationship fields data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a ember model like this:

```
var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    users: belongsTo('user'),
    message: attr(),
    user_id: attr(),
    inquiry_id: attr()
});
```

in my route i want to save it like this:

```
 var createMessage = this.store.createRecord('message', {
        'message': "this is sample message",
        'user_id': 1,
        'inquiry_id': 1
    });
createMessage.save();
```

But i saw in my request ember data also added users fields. I don't to send this field in my request. Is there any way I can do this. I want to use users relationship field only for get request not for post request. 
**Version Ember: 1.6.1 and
Ember-data: 1.0.0-beta.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Ember Data will include any attributes you have defined on your model, regardless of whether or not they've been set to a value. If you need to remove an extra field from the request, you can create a custom serializer and override the `serialize` method to remove it from the default serialization:

```
App.MessageSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serialize: function(message, options) {
    var json = this._super(message, options);
    delete json.users;
    return json;
  }
});
```

---

**However**, depending on the complexity of your app, things will probably go easier for you overall if you can stick to a single field to represent a relationship, rather than trying to manage two different fields for getting and setting the user(s). If you are able to access the desired User model and can set it to the `user` field, Ember can take care of the serialization to the correct field on submit.

Obviously it may need to be customized based on your server; as it appears your server is expecting it to be formatted `user_id`, I'm guessing you might want to look into Ember Data's [ActiveModelSerializer class](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: Hi, @gorner I am using ActiveModelSerializer and also have single field to represent relationship but I am getting error: **Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'user' record to this relationship Error: Assertion Failed: You can only add a 'user' record to this relationship**

Answer (score 1):

As @gorner suggested I modified my model like this:

```
var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    message: attr(),
    user: belongsTo('user'),
    inquiry: belongsTo('inquiry')
});
```

so, now I have single field to represent relationship. Also I am modifying

```
serializeBelongsTo method like this: 
    serializeBelongsTo: function(record, json, relationship){
        var key = relationship.key;
        var belongsTo = Ember.get(record, key);
        key = this.keyForRelationship ? this.keyForRelationship(key, "belongsTo") : key;
        json[key+'_id'] = Ember.get(belongsTo, 'id'); //my backend support field name underscore
    }
```